# Cannot see `/etc/ansible/hosts` in MacOs

Tags: macos, ansible

I have installed ansible using `brew` and also using `pip` I could not locate the hosts file anywhere. Where can I find it?

Comment: I don't use `ansible`, but my guess would be `/usr/local/etc`.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *"I could not locate the hosts file anywhere. Where can I find it?"*

A: Dump the configuration and find out the path. For example

```
$ ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_HOST_LIST
DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(/home/admin/.ansible.cfg) = [u'/home/admin/.ansible/hosts']
```

Comment: Typed in the command, this was the output `DEFAULT_HOST_LIST(default) = [u'/etc/ansible/hosts']` however, I could not find the file "no file there"

Comment: Then create one that fits your needs. See [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-to-build-your-inventory).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just got it. Actually it was simple but I missed it :) 
Run the command

```
ansible --version
```

The value of the key `configured module search path` is where the hosts file located

Answer (score 0):

By default in Mac you would not get file  `/etc/ansible/hosts`

Work around is to set ENV variable

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/Users/your-user-name/.ansible.cfg
```

and create a file.

```
 ~/.ansible.cfg
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
DEFAULT_HOST_LIST = /Users/your-user-name/.ansible/hosts
inventory =  /Users/your-user-name/.ansible/hosts
```